# Parsing Standard Input in Java

Tags: java, parsing, input, ascii

I am writing a program to perform Gaussian elimination.  I have a version that works perfectly fine using **file** input (Java.util.Scanner, Java.io.File), but for the assignment the program needs to accept **standard input**.

For example,  my program works perfectly if I were to execute the following command on the command line (using input1.txt, my input file, as a command line argument):

```
java GaussianElim input1.txt > outputfile.txt
```

But, it needs to accept standard input, for which the command would be:

```
java GaussianElim < input1.txt > outputfile.txt
```

So, my question is: does Java have any type of class available for parsing standard ASCII input?  I've considered writing my own method to parse the ASCII characters I read in and if there's no built-in Java functionality for my needs I certainly will.

Here is what a sample input file would look like (// indicates a comment added by me)

```
3             // indicates the size of the matrix
// Matrix layout
3 2 4 | 19    // row 1 | answer column
1 1 -1 | 0    // row 2 | answer column
2 -5 1 | -5   // row 3 | answer column
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that easy... Thank you very much!